# Serial port communication using java via internet

Tags: java, serial-port

Can I use java serial port communication to send and receive data across internet between two remote computers(conneced to different LANs) ? How to open a such port ?

Comment: What do you mean by "serial port"; a db-9 or db-25? Or do you mean a TCP socket?

Comment: I mean TCP sockets. I want to send data as Serializable objects. @ElliottFrisch